# python - _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg" for ttk.Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make background with color in my GUI with 2 tabs, and i run into this problem, maybe some advice?

here is the code:

```
colors = ["Blue", "Gold", "Red"]

def radCall():
    radSel=radVar.get()
    if radSel == 0: tab1.configure(bg=colors[0])
    elif radSel == 1: tab1.configure(bg=colors[1])
    elif radSel == 2: tab1.configure(bg=colors[2])

radVar = tk.IntVar()
radVar.set(99)

for col in range(3):
    curRad = tk.Radiobutton(mighty, text=colors[col], variable=radVar, 
                            value=col, command=radCall)
    curRad.grid(column=col, row=13, sticky=tk.W)
```

and here is the problem:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__                           >C:/Users/HP/
    return self.func(*args)                                        top/Kuliah/Se
  File "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\Kuliah\Semester 2\Information TechnologI_jualbeli_Day\Python\week5\Informasi Jual Beli\GUI_jualbeli_Dazan.py", line 277, in radCall
if radSel == 0: tab1.configure(bg=colors[0])
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))    
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

any idea?

Comment: What is `tab1`.

Comment: it's a variable to make tab 1

Comment: `ttk` widgets don't usually accept `bg`, they have `Style`, so you have to use it and change color inside that.

Comment: how to do that?
but in this case the tab1 is a frame

Comment: A `ttk.Frame` ?

Comment: yes it is, the code is `tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)`

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. `ttk.Frame` doesn't support the `bg` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To play around with themes of `ttk` widgets, you should use `Style`, which is like:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('first.TFrame',background='red')
s.configure('second.TFrame',background='green')
s.configure('third.TFrame',background='blue')
```

Then your if statements would be:

```
def radCall():
    radSel=radVar.get()
    if radSel == 0: tab1.configure(style='first.TFrame')
    elif radSel == 1: tab1.configure(style='second.TFrame')
    elif radSel == 2: tab1.configure(style='third.TFrame')
```

Also in your case, you have to define, `colors` on top and then use `colors[0]` and so on, with `configure()`.

You could also try this out to create just one theme and keep editing it:

```
s = ttk.Style()
.... # Rest of code

def radCall():
    radSel=radVar.get()
    if radSel == 0:
        s.configure('custom.TFrame',background=colors[0])
        tab1.configure(style='custom.TFrame')
    elif radSel == 1:
        s.configure('custom.TFrame',background=colors[1])
        tab1.configure(style='custom.TFrame')
    elif radSel == 2:
        s.configure('cusom.TFrame',background=colors[2])
        tab1.configure(style='custom.TFrame')
```