# Is there a different way, to change the listbox attributes from a combobox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm searching for a better solution the whole time. Butt I can't find anything about this. My question is, can i change the listbox, without  `root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", "#1d2128")` for the combobox? So it's working, but i want the changes near my created combobox and not at the `root`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")

# listbox in combobox attributtes
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", "#1d2128")
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground", "#8b9ebf")
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Font", "Courier")


# create a combobox
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly', "#1d2128")])
style.map('TCombobox', foreground=[('readonly', "#8b9ebf")])
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', "#1d2128")])
style.map('TCombobox', background=[('readonly', "#8b9ebf")])
comboBox_Options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
comboBox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=comboBox_Options, style="TCombobox", font="Consolas")
comboBox.set("Option 1")
comboBox["state"] = "readonly"
comboBox.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you can use `style.configure('TCombobox',opt)`. Just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67000235/13382000)

Comment: this changes the combobox background (which you can see when you look at it), but not the listbox in the combobox (when you drop down the combobox)

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to access a widgets option database. You can wait for more suggestions.

Comment: ok. but thank you (for other widgets `configure` works fine, but this combobox is a liitle bit difficult...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to configure the popdown listbox of a combobox:

```py
def config_combobox_popdown(cb, **kw):
    # popdown listbox
    popdown = cb.tk.eval("ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow %s" % cb)
    args = []
    for key, val in kw.items():
        args.append("-"+key)
        args.append(val)
    cb.tk.call("%s.f.l" % popdown, "configure", *args)

...

comboBox_Options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
comboBox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=comboBox_Options, style="TCombobox", font="Consolas")
comboBox.set("Option 1")
comboBox["state"] = "readonly"
comboBox.pack()

config_combobox_popdown(comboBox, font="Courier", foreground="#8b9ebf", background="#1d2128")
```

Comment: Ok... wow .. it works perfectly. But very hard code for me (because I'm a beginner). I saw this `*args` and `**kwargs` in different codes, but I actually don't know how to use it. But I will figure it out. So..  again thanks!